# Calling a validation from within another custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I want to have two different custom validators, but would like one of the validators to reference the other:

```
class URLFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # ... validates the format of a URL is correct
  end    
end

class URLReachableValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # ... validates the URL is reachable
  end    
end
```

How can I reference the `URLFormatValidator` within the `URLReachableValidator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class URLReachableValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    format_validator = URLFormatValidator.new
    format_validator.validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  end    
end
```

But I would just use inheritance or a mix-in to share functionality instead.

```
class URLValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  # shared funtionality ...
end

class URLFormatValidator < URLValidator 
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # ...
  end    
end

class URLReachableValidator < URLValidator 
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # ...
  end    
end
```